# Confused about Htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a little bit of trouble with my Htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testwebsite/

RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php
```

What i'm trying to accomplish is the following: Whenever the client visits localhost/testwebsite/index.php, he must be redirect to the clean url (localhost/testwebsite/home). Whenever the visitor visits localhost/testwebsite/home, he must stay there but the content of index.php will still be shown.

Currently whenever I visit localhost/testwebsite/home, the content of index.php has been shown, but whenever I visit localhost/testwebsite/index.php, the client still see's the "ugly" url.

I looked up information all over the internet but the method of how mod_rewriting works just won't get inside of my head. Help would be appericiated, thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure how it achieves it, but Mod_rewrite is indeed a pain in the pong to master. I found Lots and Lots of trial and error helped. And learning REGEX too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do. You can use this code in your .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testwebsite/
#redirect index.php to the pretty URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [A-Z]{3,}\ /testwebsite/index\.php
RewriteRule ^ home? [R=301,L]
#internally rewrite pretty URL to index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Could you may give me an explanation of how this exactly works? Thanks in advanced

Comment: I pretty much did in the rule. But just look up the variables on Apache's site. Basically we check the request, and if it's index.php then we redirect to /home. If /home is requested we internally redirect to index.php.

Comment: And what if I do this in PHP itself? So for example, asking the REQUEST_URI and then validate if the user visits index.php, if so redirect him with the header function to the clean url? Dumb question, since it's working but i'd also like to know if this is a "properly" way to do this :P

Comment: Why would you need to mix the 2? using Apache to handle redirects is actually faster. .htaccess is read and executed before server side code(PHP). So for performance wise, I would leave it. Also please check this answer as accepted.

Comment: You just said it was working for you?? `since it's working but i'd also like to know if this is a "properly" way to do this`

Comment: The method I was telling you, was working (the php code). Now i've tried your code but it doesn't seem to work. Not sure why though.

Comment: Where is your htaccess file located?

Comment: In the root of my directory testwebsite next beside index.php

Comment: And which part is not working? You didn't really give any info

Comment: Well, whenever I visit localhost/testwebsite/index.php, the index.php still stays there, it won't be redirected to localhost/testwebsite/home

Comment: is testwebsite your root? or document root or is it a subfolder?

Comment: testwebsite is the root of where my website files are located in, the full path is: C:\wamp\www\testwebsite\

Comment: Ok so you defined your `document root` as `c:\wamp\www\testwebsite` in your apache config or just c:\wamp\www

Comment: The .htaccess base path is still the same, I left it like you wrote it. If this is what you mean, I haven't changed anything in the apache configuration. Only enabled the rewrite module

Comment: Try change the line to this `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [A-Z]{3,}\ /testwebsite/index\.php`